# How does Aloglia show synonyms for a entered search term?

Tags: search, algolia, synonym

How does [Aloglia search API](https://www.algolia.com/) list & **show synonyms** of the type search query entered by user in the search field?

#### Example flow

1. User types following: `airplane`
2. User should see a list of these synonyms: `aircraft`, `jet`, `plane`

Comment: Please share what you tried (pseudo-code) or what you researched so far. See also [mcve].

Comment: @Sam they already have related words saved in their database...